# asyncio: prevent task from being cancelled twice

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

Sometimes, my coroutine cleanup code includes some blocking parts (in the `asyncio` sense, i.e. they may yield).

I try to design them carefully, so they don't block indefinitely. So "by contract", coroutine must never be interrupted once it's inside its cleanup fragment.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to prevent this, and bad things occur when it happens (whether it's caused by actual double `cancel` call; or when it's almost finished by itself, doing cleanup, and happens to be cancelled from elsewhere).

Theoretically, I can delegate cleanup to some other function, protect it with a `shield`, and surround it with `try`-`except` loop, but it's just ugly.

Is there a Pythonic way to do so?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def foo():
    """
    This is the function in question,
    with blocking cleanup fragment.
    """

    try:
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Interrupted during work")
        raise
    finally:
        print("I need just a couple more seconds to cleanup!")
        try:
            # upload results to the database, whatever
            yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("Interrupted during cleanup :(")
        else:
            print("All cleaned up!")

@asyncio.coroutine
def interrupt_during_work():
    # this is a good example, all cleanup
    # finishes successfully

    t = asyncio.async(foo())

    try:
        yield from asyncio.wait_for(t, 0.5)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    else:
        assert False, "should've been timed out"

    t.cancel()

    # wait for finish
    try:
        yield from t
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass

@asyncio.coroutine
def interrupt_during_cleanup():
    # here, cleanup is interrupted

    t = asyncio.async(foo())

    try:
        yield from asyncio.wait_for(t, 1.5)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    else:
        assert False, "should've been timed out"

    t.cancel()

    # wait for finish
    try:
        yield from t
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass

@asyncio.coroutine
def double_cancel():
    # cleanup is interrupted here as well
    t = asyncio.async(foo())

    try:
        yield from asyncio.wait_for(t, 0.5)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    else:
        assert False, "should've been timed out"

    t.cancel()

    try:
        yield from asyncio.wait_for(t, 0.5)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass
    else:
        assert False, "should've been timed out"

    # although double cancel is easy to avoid in 
    # this particular example, it might not be so obvious
    # in more complex code
    t.cancel()

    # wait for finish
    try:
        yield from t
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass

@asyncio.coroutine
def comain():
    print("1. Interrupt during work")
    yield from interrupt_during_work()

    print("2. Interrupt during cleanup")
    yield from interrupt_during_cleanup()

    print("3. Double cancel")
    yield from double_cancel()

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(comain())
    loop.run_until_complete(task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `asyncio.shield` is the recommended way for your problem.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov bare `shield` is not enough, unfortunately. The function calling `shield` will still receive `CancelledError`.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing a simple function that provides a stronger shield, so to speak.

Unlike `asyncio.shield`, which protects the callee, but raises `CancelledError` in its caller, this function suppresses `CancelledError` altogether.

The drawback is that this function doesn't allow you to handle `CancelledError` later. You won't see whether it has ever happened. Something *slightly* more complex would be required to do so.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def super_shield(arg, *, loop=None):
    arg = asyncio.async(arg)
    while True:
        try:
            return (yield from asyncio.shield(arg, loop=loop))
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            continue
```

Answer (score 1):

I found WGH's solution when encountering a similar problem. I'd like to await a thread, but regular asyncio cancellation (with or without shield) will just cancel the awaiter and leave the thread floating around, uncontrolled. Here is a modification of `super_shield` that optionally allows reacting on cancel requests and also handles cancellation from within the awaitable:

```
await protected(aw, lambda: print("Cancel request"))
```

This guarantees that the awaitable has finished or raised `CancelledError` from within. If your task could be cancelled by other means (e.g. setting a flag observed by a thread), you can use the optional cancel callback to enable cancellation.

Implementation:

```
async def protect(aw, cancel_cb: typing.Callable = None):
    """
    A variant of `asyncio.shield` that protects awaitable as well
    as the awaiter from being cancelled.

    Cancellation events from the awaiter are turned into callbacks
    for handling cancellation requests manually.

    :param aw: Awaitable.
    :param cancel_cb: Optional cancellation callback.
    :return: Result of awaitable.
    """
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(aw)
    while True:
        try:
            return await asyncio.shield(task)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            if task.done():
                raise
            if cancel_cb is not None:
                cancel_cb()
```